# What is the big hole at the bottom of the vertical stabilizer on the Boeing 717?

Tags: equipment, dc-9-family

What is the big hole located on the forward vertical stabilizer's bottom used for?

[image]
([Image source](http://www.planes.cz/en/photo/1218046/b717-2bl-ei-exi-volotea-airlines-voe-v7-skiathos-jsi-lgsk))